# Как воспроизвести звук не прерывая (паралельно) выполнению других команд

Tags: python, аудио

**Как мне воспроизвести звук асинхронно?**

Пробовал pyglet (келых три строчки кода так еще и после выполнения звука все останавливается), playsound (просто не играл звук при `block=False`), `just_playback` (вообще не установился), pygame (слишком много весит). И у всех одна и та же проблема: приостанавливается выполнение кода. Есть ли какая-то библиотека которая могла бы в одну строчку кода, асинхронно воспроизвести звук.

```
#pg - pyautogui
shut = pg.confirm(text="Завершить єпично работу ПК?", title="Єпичное завершение2023 ", buttons=["OK", "НЕТ"])
if shut == "OK": 
pg.hotkey("win", "r") 
time.sleep(0.5) 
pg.typewrite("cmd") 
pg.press("enter") 
time.sleep(0.5) 
out = pyglet.resource.media("outro.mp3") 
out.play() 
pyglet.app.run() #И ниже код не выполняеться.
pg.typewrite("shutdown /s /t 17") 
pg.press("enter")
```

P.S: Если кто-то еще и подскажет библиотеку с возможностью установки и получения значения громкости от души поблагодарю

Comment: Просто нужно проигрывание музыки делать в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Библиотеки https://pythonpip.ru/osnovy/10-audiomoduley-python-dlya-vosproizvedeniya-i-zapisi

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, свои несколько строчек кода, которые так тормозят.

Comment: @СергейКох добавил

Comment: @Александр Спасибо, обязательно что-то попробую из этого списка

Comment: Отступов эпичных не хватает, и минимально-воспроизводимого примера. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Здесь почему код дальше не выполняется. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555284/python-stop-when-pyglet-app-run-applied

Comment: Если вы хотите с музыкой, то в pyglet есть те же функции управления клавиатурой и мышкой, что и в pyautogui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кстати в pyglet можно регулировать громкость, да там вообще много чего можно.

```
import time
from threading import Thread

from pyglet.media import Player, load


class MiniPlayer(Player):
    def __init__(self, path_to_file: str):
        super().__init__()
        source = load(path_to_file)
        self.queue(source)

    def on_play(self):
        return self.play()

    def on_pause(self):
        return self.pause()

    def get_volume(self):
        return self.volume

    def set_volume(self, value):
        self.volume = value


def change_volume(player: MiniPlayer):
    for value in range(10, 100, 10):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(value / 100)
        player.set_volume(value / 100)


def main():
    # TO DO ваш код до
    mini_player = MiniPlayer("song.mp3")
    mini_player.on_play()
    print(f"Громкость до: {mini_player.get_volume()}")
    mini_player.set_volume(0.5)
    print(f"Громкость после: {mini_player.get_volume()}")
    # TO DO ваш код после
    print("ваш код после")
    # Имитация кода после
    Thread(target=change_volume, args=(mini_player,)).start()
    time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

P.S. Мудрил что бы запустить в одтельном потоке но так и не вышло.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Буду тоже мудрить, но уже в проекте)

Comment: Можно ещё и стрелочку вверх :-)

Comment: Вам мудрить по сути не чего не нужно, ваша задача в вопросе решена.

Comment: Я бы с радостью поставил но у меня репутация не позволяет. А так большое спасибо, все отлично работает. Отдельное спасибо за список библиотек.